# Read lines of file, put each line into an array, then print

Tags: c, string, io

I just figured out how to do this with integers so decided to give it a go with strings and got stuck.

Here is what is in my file "kw":

```
keyword0
keyword1
keyword2
keyword3
```

With this current code I'm getting "error: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'char **'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    FILE *pFile;

    pFile = fopen("kw", "r");

    if (pFile != NULL) {

        char *a[3];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", &a[i]);
            printf("%s\n", a[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this code:

- You are going through four elements of the array `a`, while the array has only three elements.
- You did not allocate space for the strings that you are reading with `scanf`.
- You do not pass the address of address when you read strings.

To fix the first problem, change `<=` for `!=` or `<`, like this:

```
for(i = 0; i != 3; i++)
```

To fix the second and the third problem, use `malloc`:

```
a[i] = malloc(21*sizeof(char));
fscanf(pFile, "%20s", a[i]);
```

Once you are done with the data that you allocated, don't forget to free the strings:

```
for(i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
    free(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: actually, the code is fine with "for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)" that is supposing he fixes the array a to hold 4 elements. But you should probably use "for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)" although it's the performance gain is trivial, it used to be much faster to use "<" over "=". Other than that, the above answer is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thanks a bunch.